# How do i perform q-learning in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get the row number and column latter in excel this is what I have:

[image]

In H1 I have 4,4 so the excel should check from A22:A6 column and return A5 in I1 but I am getting $A$2 using this formula `=CELL("address",INDEX(A2:A6,H1),0)`. Anyone know what I am doing wrong plus I want to remove that $ signs.

Comment: `=Cell("address",Index(A2:A6,Match(H1,A2:A6),1))`

Comment: @Kyle the formula gives me an error?

Comment: Really? I just tested this and it worked exactly as expected on my machine. What is the data type of cell H1?

Comment: @Kyle It wasn't working with a big dataset because I had some empty cells on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

See the image. This is structured identical, and you can see that is the formula I used.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
="A"&MATCH(H1,A:A,0)
```